# How to join SQL tables and return values that match two possible values?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got two tables.

```
pos.transaction:
- Id (primary key)
- MainframeTransactionSequenceNumber (string)
- TransactionNumber (string)

pos.payment:
- Id (primary key)
- TransactionId (foreign key)
- TenderSubTypeId (int)
- AmountBaseCurrency (decimal)
```

How can I find out all the `TransactionNumbers` that have at least two payments where the `TenderSubTypeId = 31` and `TenderSubTypeId = 37` and both their `AmountBaseCurrency < 0`?

This query below that I've created returns data where there's at least one of the two `TenderSubTypeIds` but how can I check for both in a `Transaction` and return just the `TransactionNumber`?

```
select * from pos.[transaction] t
left join pos.[payment] p on t.id = p.transactionid
where (p.TenderSubTypeId = 31 or p.TenderSubTypeId = 37)
and t.AmountTotalBaseCurrency < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `HAVING` clauses inside a subquery. Each clause counts up the number of `payment` for a particular `TenderSubTypeId`. This avoids having to do two lookups on the table.

```sql
SELECT
  t.*
FROM pos.transaction t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM pos.payment p 
    WHERE t.id = p.transactionid
      AND p.TenderSubTypeId IN (31, 37)
      AND t.AmountTotalBaseCurrency < 0
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p.TenderSubTypeId = 31 THEN 1 END) > 0
       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN p.TenderSubTypeId = 37 THEN 1 END) > 0
);
```

You could make it one clause using `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.TenderSubTypeId) = 2` but that requires a sort on `p.TenderSubTypeId`.

Comment: I get a 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.' error on the closing bracket on the third from bottom line next to 31.

Comment: Sorry should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `EXISTS` predicates that check the related table.

For example:

```
select *
from transaction t
where exists (select 1 from payment p where p.transactionid = t.id 
              and p.tendersubtype = 31 and amounttotalbasecurrency < 0)
  and exists (select 1 from payment p where p.transactionid = t.id 
              and p.tendersubtype = 37 and amounttotalbasecurrency < 0)
```

Comment: The two select statements are missing the joins (?)

Comment: @Bhav Good catch. I think I need a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join the `pos.[transaction]` table with the `pos.[payment]` table twice, filtering for payments with specific `TenderSubTypeId` values and negative `AmountBaseCurrency`. Then group the results by `TransactionNumber` and select only those groups that have at least two distinct payments, providing the `TransactionNumbers` that satisfy your condition

```
SELECT t.TransactionNumber
FROM pos.[transaction] t
JOIN pos.[payment] p1 ON t.Id = p1.TransactionId
JOIN pos.[payment] p2 ON t.Id = p2.TransactionId
WHERE p1.TenderSubTypeId = 31
  AND p1.AmountBaseCurrency < 0
  AND p2.TenderSubTypeId = 37
  AND p2.AmountBaseCurrency < 0
GROUP BY t.TransactionNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p1.Id) >= 2
```